# What is the meaning of adding/subtracting a fraction in a summation limit inside a limit?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

In [Wolfram Alpha entry 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Limit%5BSum%5BLog%5B2*k%5D%2C+%7Bk%2C+1%2C+n%7D%5D+-+Sum%5BLog%5B2*k+-+1%5D%2C+%7Bk%2C+1%2C+n+%2B+1%2F2%7D%5D%2C+n+-%3E+Infinity%5D) the following is claimed to be true:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \left(\sum _{k=1}^n \log (2 k)-\sum _{k=1}^{n+\frac{1}{2}} \log (2 k-1)\right)=\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$$

> What is the meaning of adding a fraction like $\frac{1}{2}$ in the upper summation
> limit in the second sum, inside the limit?
>
> Is it a bug a or a feature?

Compare to [Wolfram Alpha entry 2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Limit%5BSum%5BLog%5B2*k%5D%2C+%7Bk%2C+1%2C+n%7D%5D+-+Sum%5BLog%5B2*k+-+1%5D%2C+%7Bk%2C+1%2C+n%7D%5D%2C+n+-%3E+Infinity%5D) where the fraction $\frac{1}{2}$ in the upper summation limit of the second sum has been left out:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \left(\sum _{k=1}^n \log (2 k)-\sum _{k=1}^{n} \log (2 k-1)\right)=\infty$$

I get the same results in Mathematica 8.0.1:

```
Limit[Sum[Log[2*k], {k, 1, n}] - Sum[Log[2*k - 1], {k, 1, n + 1/2}], 
 n -> Infinity]
Limit[Sum[Log[2*k], {k, 1, n}] - Sum[Log[2*k - 1], {k, 1, n}], 
 n -> Infinity]
```

and as well as:

```
Limit[Sum[Log[2*k], {k, 1, n - 1/4}] - Sum[Log[2*k - 1], {k, 1, n + 1/4}], n -> Infinity]
Limit[Sum[Log[2*k], {k, 1, n}] - Sum[Log[2*k - 1], {k, 1, n + 1/4}], n -> Infinity]
```

The only support I was able to find in the documentation for `Sum` is:

"The limits of summation need not be numbers. They can be Infinity or symbolic expressions."

Comment: The series is absolutely divergent. A sum depends on the order of summation, here powitive and negative seperately. A numerical approximation tests convergence on the last summands. That is of course nonsense for the differenence of to diverging sums.  Any plot for the expression shows an alternating, log-divergent step function. Just set n=2m and n=2m+1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluate the sums without `Limit`, so that you understand what limit is being computed. The problem has nothing to do with `Limit`. It's a bug in `Sum[]`.

```
Sum[Log[2*k - 1], {k, 1, a}]
% /. a -> n + 1/2
% == Sum[Log[2*k - 1], {k, 1, n + 1/2}]
(*
Log[2^a Pochhammer[1/2, a]]
Log[2^(1/2 + n) Pochhammer[1/2, 1/2 + n]]
True
*)
```

Arguably, it's a "bug" in the user input. A full specification at least has non-erroneous behavior (does not evaluate):

```
Sum[Log[2*k - 1], {k, 1, n + 1/2}, 
 Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers]
(*
Sum[Log[-1 + 2 k], {k, 1, 1/2 + n}, 
 Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers]
*)
```

Comment: Note `DiscreteLimit[
 Sum[Log[2*k], {k, 1, n}] - Sum[Log[2*k - 1], {k, 1, n + 1/2}], 
 n -> Infinity]` returns `1/2 Log[\[Pi]/2]` which can more forcefully be argued to be a bug. However `DiscreteLimit[
 Sum[Log[2*k], {k, 1, n}] - Sum[Log[2*k - 1], {k, 1, n + 1/2}], 
 n -> Infinity, Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers]` does not evaluate, even though the sums evaluate as above.

Comment: It is a bug since n+1/2 is the same as n when you go to Infinity also it makes no sense unless it rounds so 1 + 1/2 = 1.5 = 2.0 or it sums from 1.5: 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, ...

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников Isn't the `Sum[...]` correct if `n + 1/2` is an integer? There's is nothing in the input of the sum to `n + 1/2` that says that `n` is an integer.

Comment: If n + 1/2 is an integer then the other sum that also has n will not be an integer. That is the same n.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников `Sum[Log[2*k - 1], {k, 1, n + 1/2}]` is computed independently from `Sum[Log[2*k], {k, 1, n}]`. There is nothing that ties the two instances of `n` together. They are computed before `Limit` is called. To me, the point is that the computation does not reflect the standard interpretation of the mathematical statement in the OP's first TeX formula.

Comment: "Nothing that ties" But is that correct? I understand that it just finds a closed form of the Sum, after that you can indeed put anything inside, but that is just insane.

Comment: "'Nothing that ties' But is that correct?" Yes, I believe so. Each sum is computed independently. Then the results are subtracted. Then the difference is passed to `Limit[]`, at which point and not earlier are the two values of `n` treated as representing the same (complex) number. -- I don't know what `Sum[a[k], {k, 1, n + 1/2}]` means if `n` represents an integer. If we have a specific integer, such `Sum[a[k], {k, 1, 3 + 1/2}]`, then it is the same as `Sum[a[k], {k, 1, 3}]`. But it may not be true for the symbol `n`.

Comment: "then it is the same as" No, it is not. In calculus I only ever saw indeces that must be integers when they are inserted, so this requires some new definition. I mean this is the same as with limit of a sequence and limit of the function. Bottom line: there should be a change in the result, just as there is when you find closed form first. I imagine the definition is indeed: find the closed form first.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников Not sure "in calculus" matters to how a program in Mathematica is actually executed. We seem to differ on this. I don't dispute what you say about normal mathematics. In Mma, the indices in `Sum[a[k],{k,1,n+1/2}]` are integers. The indices in `Sum[a[k],{k,1/2,7/2}]` are not (I've never seen a sum like this in math). The following can be criticized, since it treats `21/2` as an integer: `Sum[Log[2*k],{k,1,10+1/2},Method->"Symbolic"]`. But I expected it. I learned long ago the limitations of modeling math with Mma. Besides, one should use `DiscreteLimit` not `Limit` here

Answer (score 1):

`Limit` is assuming that `n` is continuous, and so the sums are simplified to give results for non-integers.  You can see this with `TracePrint`, it eventually evaluates:

```
Log[2^n Pochhammer[1,n]]-Log[2^(1/2+n) Pochhammer[1/2,1/2+n]]
```

This function does converge.  However, it doesn't equal the sums for any `n` (the first `Log[...Pochhammer...` agrees with the first sum on $\mathbb Z$, and the second agrees with the second sum on $\mathbb Z+\frac12$, but together they don't agree anywhere).

[image: first sum]
[image: second sum]

I don't know how to make the `Limit` evaluate if you explicitly write `Floor[n+1/2]` in the bound, but Roland's comment is correct.

The story is the same for your other functions (although the last pair diverges even after 'continuousization').